# optimize perfomance in sockets java

Tags: java, performance, sockets

My application uses sockets and threads to send real-time data that is receiving to clients that connect to it. To do so, the steps are:

- Connects to the data server and then waits for clients
- Launch a thread to discuss incoming data, format them and send them out to customers, if any.
- When a client connects, it opens a thread for him through which data will be sent.
- Finally, use another thread to test you are receiving and sending data, otherwise it is reconnected to the source.

The data received from the source are stored in an array waiting to be processed by the thread.
In each client thread, the received data is also stored in an array to be sent.
The purpose of this is that no jams in receiving or sending data.
the data is delayed 10 seconds or more to reach customers

What I can do to optimize performance?
This is running on a windows server, can you recommend any profiler?

Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT:
The data are strings of variable length.
A part of code is:
// create source socket in class implements Runnable and then waits client

```
Socket entrada = new Socket(servidor,Integer.parseInt(puerto));
InputStream sIn = entrada.getInputStream();  
        while (!error) {  
          try {
              s = salida.accept();
              clientes.add(new ClientThread(s));              
// run
while (((c = sIn.read()) != -1) && ((clientes.size() > 0))) {
if (c != 13 && c != 10) {
cad += (char) c;
}
if (c == 13) received[i] = cad

// In SendThread, run
// format received[i] and send result
for (i=0; i < clientes.size(); i++) {
  clientes.get(i).SendData(result);
}


// In ClientThread:
OutputString s1out = socket.getOutputStream();
// SendData
sending[i] = result;
// run
if cad forsending
              for (int j = 0;j<res.length();j++){
                try {
                    s1out.write((int)res.charAt(j));          
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                  }
              }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, only 1 client is connected. In the future, they are 10. Thanks.

Comment: With few data works, but when it send all data produces delays. Thanks.

Comment: You are going to have to post some code. From your description the system should work optimally. Your code may be introducing bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much data you are sending, it could be the way you are handling streams.

`c = sIn.read()` reads a only a few bytes at a time. Try wrapping it with a [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and using `readLine()`. BufferedReader will read a few kb at a time, which is much more efficient. `readLine()` will also break inputs into lines for you, which will simplify the code somewhat.

On the client connection, PrintWriter may help you to output whole lines in one go.