# BufferedWriter vs PrintWriter with sockets?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

In this case, [optimize perfomance in sockets java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813570/optimize-perfomance-in-sockets-java),
what is better, with sockets, BufferedWriter or PrintWriter?

The socket in every thread (client) send the formatted data in lines, string with CR. In BufferedWriter, i would use newLine after write()?

Thanks for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The 
[Javadoc of BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) specifically states:

> Unless prompt output is required, it is advisable to wrap a BufferedWriter around any Writer whose write() operations may be costly, such as FileWriters and OutputStreamWriters. For example,
>
> ```
>  PrintWriter out
>    = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("foo.out")));
> ```

Comment: I test 3 options:           out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);          
out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())); out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())), true); and the option with less delay is the first. When i execute flush() after println, the delay too dismiss. Why is it? Thanks.

Comment: What you _should_ do is use a `BufferedWriter` and close the file after you're completely done, instead of flushing it after every line.

Answer (score 0):

PrintWriter swallows all exceptions. Unless you use great care to check for errors every time you call it, and are prepared not to know what those errors actually were, it shouldn't normally be used over a network, where you need to know about all exceptions. Use BufferedWriter.